# User input Arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, bluej

I was wondering if its possible to store an object into a arraylist where the user wants it. For my program its storing the users data into a cell of their choice via an "account number" but every time I type in a new account number it says that the array isn't big enough basically. Here is my code. If anyone could help that would be appreciated.

```
ArrayList <Account> account = new ArrayList<Account>();
int accountNumber;
String nCity;
String nState;
String nZipCode;
String nLastName;
String nAddress;
String firstName;
String nAccount;

public void newAccount()
{
    Account a = new Account();
    a.firstName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your first name?");
    a.nLastName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your last name?");
    a.nAddress = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current address?");
    a.nCity= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current city?");
    a.nState = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current State?");
    a.nZipCode = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What's your current Zip Code?");
    String num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("What do you want your account number to be?");
    accountNumber = Integer.parseInt(num);
    account.add(accountNumber, a);
```

Comment: make the list big enough before adding or use a `Map` structure.

Comment: @jlordo how do I make it big enough, I can't seem to find where to put the value for how big the array list should be?

Comment: @Lightning.. Are you sure you are able to compile that code? As it stands, your code will not even compile. How are you running it exactly?

Comment: @RohitJain it compiled for me and ran but then it said "java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 0 (in java.util.ArrayList). I need the initial size to be a huge number so new accounts can be added as they are created.

Comment: @Lightning `while (list.size() < needed_size) list.add(null);` But a `Map` would be much better for your use case.

Comment: I'm surprised that you didn't get any compiler error at: - `account.add(accountNumber, a);`

Comment: @RohitJain `ArrayList.add(int index, E element)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `HashMap` and use the account number as the key

```
    Map<Integer,Account> account =new Hashmap<Integer,Account>();
    account.put(accountNumber,a);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have created an `ArrayList<Account>` and you are adding elements into it in the form of `key-value` pair.

If you want to add that way, you probably need a `HashMap`: -

```
Map<Integer, Account> accounts = new HashMap<Integer, Account>();
```

then, to add entry in it, you can use `Map#put()` method: -

```
accounts.put(accountNumber, a);
```

Answer (score 1):

Agree with the above suggestions about using Map.

Your "array isn't big enough" is simply because you are trying to specify the index of the List while you haven't initialize the indexes yet.

Simply, you are using this method of List:

add(int index, E element) 
          Inserts the specified element at the specified position in this list.

The keyword is INSERT.
So, imagine if your "accountNumber" is 100, and you don't have the 99 elements before it, trying to insert will make no sense in logic because you are inserting into nowhere.

JavaSE6 API says under this method:

IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())

By the way, another solution, if available to you, besides using Map is to have accountNumber as another field of Account, and you can use List now with the single-argument add() method.